# Change Password URL missing In forgot Password mail In Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email

I'm requesting Wordpress for Forgot password. I also got the mail from wordpress site.

But the change password url is missing from it.

The mail is as below :

Someone requested that the password be reset for the following account: https://www.example.com/ Username: abc@example.com If this was a mistake, just ignore this email and nothing will happen. To reset your password, visit the following address:

The link is not receiving in the mail.

What should be reason for it ?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using retrieve_password_message filter

```
add_filter( 'retrieve_password_message', 'modify_forgot_mail_contnet', 10, 2 );
function modify_forgot_mail_contnet($message, $key){
          // here $message it the mail content , which you can modify as per your requirment and $key is activation key

         // after modifying you must return $message
          return $message;
}
```